# Ionic 5.Cors issue with HttpClient Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, httpclient

Could anyone suggest please … is it possible to get it work with HttpClient on Android/iOs on real device ? I spend all day and did not find decision.

**Error.**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my.com/feeds/branding/backgrounds/cr.png' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I configure a server side, add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS` but it did not help.

I use such query.

```
 let options = {chunkedMode: false, responseType: 'arraybuffer'};
  const req = new HttpRequest('GET', mediaObj.bu_link, options);

  this.httpClient.request(req).retry(2).subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

        let file = new Blob([event.body as BlobPart], {type: 'image/png'});

        }
      }
      ,
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.logProvider.writeLog("ERROR: method saveBgImage  in AddMediaProvider class ", err);

       
      });
```

Comment: You need to allow cors on htaccess file in your server if its an image and if it a language file you need to set a header in it to allow access cors. So there is no problem with httpclient itself but the problem is that your website prevents the http requests to it , thus you need to allow your server to accept these requests by enabling cors.

Comment: We use Microsoft-IIS/8.0, not Apache.

Comment: Ok np, anything so if so it could be in web.config file so you add a condition for such thing. Google it how to solve cors issue in web.config file.

Comment: Try this link, and if it work tell me so i could save the link if needed for me in future work. https://dzone.com/articles/access-control-allow-origin-header-and-the-aspnet

Comment: Add headers to web.config did not help.

Comment: This is a real problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203288/access-control-allow-origin-not-working-with-ionic-5-app and I haven't been able to find a solution for the last two weeks.